# Matrix environments not working

Tags: amsmath, matrices, latexit

I have a strange problem. It seems I cannot use any of the matrix environments (`matrix`, `bmatrix`, `pmatrix` etc.). The following code will not render on my machine

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\begin{bmatrix}
 U_{11} & U_{12}& U_{13}& \cdots& U_{1k}\\
 U_{21} & U_{22}& U_{23}& \cdots& U_{2k}\\
 \vdots & &\vdots & &\vdots             \\
 U_{N1} & U_{N2}& U_{N3}& \cdots& U_{Nk} \\
 \end{bmatrix}

\end{document}
```

However if I just put the `bmatrix` environment code into LaTeXiT, everything works fine. I have tried even just the simplest matrix examples using several `matrix` environments and none seem to work. Is my `amsmath` package hosed somehow?

I'm running OSX 10.7.4 and am using TexShop installed via MacTeX. Here is the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12  \end{bmatrix}

?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! you need to wrap the `bmatrix` in math mode- for example `$\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}$`

Answer (score 7):

You should put them in math mode. It works in latexit as the contents are automatically wrapped inside  math mode there.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
 U_{11} & U_{12}& U_{13}& \cdots& U_{1k}\\
 U_{21} & U_{22}& U_{23}& \cdots& U_{2k}\\
 \vdots & &\vdots & &\vdots             \\
 U_{N1} & U_{N2}& U_{N3}& \cdots& U_{Nk} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user37234 If this answers your question you may want to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting clarification for your problem. I quote from a textbook named "Technical notes on the amsmath package, American Mathematical Society,Michael Downes, 1999/10/29"

> If you used the plain.tex versions of \matrix, \pmatrix, or \cases in
>   a document and then later converted the document to use the amsmath
>   package (or one of the AMS documentclasses, which automatically call
>   the amsmath package internally), the instances of those commands will
>   produce error messages. The problem is that when LATEX was originally
>   created, it adopted most of its mathematics features straight from
>   plain.tex. But in the case of \matrix, \pmatrix, \cases this was a
>   mistake|the plain.tex syntax for them is decidedly non-LATEX in style,
>   for example the fact that they use \cr instead of \ to mark line
>   breaks, and they don't use \begin and \end. In basic LATEX this
>   mistake will be perpetuated at least until LATEX3 appears, in order to
>   avoid breaking existing documents. But no existing documents that were
>   written with the amsmath package have that syntactic problem, as
>   amsmath provides proper LATEX-syntax versions of \matrix and the
>   others. The possibility of optionally allowing the plain.tex variants
>   to make document conversion easier seems illadvised since those
>   variants are so blatantly wrong in a LATEX context. The array
>   environment ought to have been used instead.

Comment: What has this to do with `bmatrix`?

Comment: I guess it's the same bug since we are talking about the ams package conflicting with plain.tex versions of matrices.

Comment: `\bmatrix` is not defined in plain TeX.